# Understanding Python basic Multiprocessing speed

Tags: python

I understand multiprocessing as a way to speed up processes, but the time behavior of these examples confuse me.

With Pool:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

t1 = time.perf_counter()
def f(x):
    m = x*x
    return m

def test():
    r = 10000000
    with Pool(processes=3) as pool:     
        result = map(f, range(r))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
    t2 = time.perf_counter()
    print("Time:", t2-t1)
Time: 0.1850741
```

Now I modify only the test function:

```
def test():
    r = 10000000
    pool = Pool(processes=3) 
    result = pool.map(f, range(r))
Time: 3.4996175
```

Without Pool:

```
import time
t1 = time.perf_counter()

def f(x):
    m = x*x
    return m

def test():
    r = 10000000
    result = map(f, range(r))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
    t2 = time.perf_counter()
    print("Time:", t2-t1)
Time: 1.3399999999996748e-05
```

These are significant time differences that I can't understand.

Comment: ``multiprocessing`` has a notable overhead for managing the processes. ``f`` does basically nothing and finishes much faster in a single process than it takes to fan it out to multiple processes.

Comment: The test with `map` is not correct. The `map` is lazy, you should iterate it to execute `f`. This should work `list(map(f, range(r)))` for example.

Comment: I see what OP is posting about: invoking with `with` seemingly runs twice as fast as without.  I tried using `r = 20000000` and `r = 40000000` and found the two tests were still proportionally `2:1`.  I proposed an edit to his question to highlight his issue better.

Comment: @RazzleShazl The two cases do *wildly* different things in the original question: the case using `with` uses the builtin map, not the one of the pool. The timings are not 2:1 but 20:1.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Ah yes I see that now!  Wish I could revoke my proposed edit...

Comment: @RazzleShazl See my above comment. "``multiprocessing`` has a notable overhead for managing the processes." That is not just starting them but also passing the tasks to them.

Comment: Thanks again @MisterMiyagi !

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. special the first one from @MisterMiyagi has helped to my understanding about multiprocessing. In the first example I forgot to set the pool: result = pool.map(f, range(r)). Now I get around 4 s, not any more 0.1850741. The meaning " lazy list" was new for me. Now I understand better was you mean.

Answer (score 0):

As has been noted, the built-in [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns an iterator or "lazy list", meanwhile [Pool.map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) returns a proper list.

Without exhausting the iterator from [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), the work in `f()` is not performed.

### `Pool.map` (multiprocess)

```
def test():
    r = 10000000
    with Pool(processes=3) as pool:
        # you now have one `pool` object within this scope
        # and its resources will be cleaned up automatically
        # when you exit this `with` scope
        result = pool.map(f, range(r))
```

### `map` built-in (single process)

As @sardok mentioned, pass the iterator into a `list()` and it will grind the iterator until exhaustion to populate that list fully.  This ensures the work is fully completed.

```
def test():
    r = 10000000
    result = list(map(f, range(r)))
```

For more efficient chunking, consider [Pool.imap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap)

### Times

Regarding your three specific times:

> Time: 0.1850741 -- lazy list, so f() was not performed
>
> Time: 3.4996175 -- looks good
>
> Time: 1.3399999999996748e-05 -- again lazy list

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. special the first one from @MisterMiyagi has helped to my understanding about multiprocessing. In the first example I forgot to set the pool: result = pool.map(f, range(r)). Now I get around 4 s, not any more 0.1850741. The meaning " lazy list" was new for me. Now I understand better was you mean.

Comment: That's great to hear @JosMar.  I learned stuff as well :)  If you found this answer useful, please consider accepting.  Thank you.